# Correct way to implement async Entity Framework repository

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous

I'm reading a lot about Entity Framework async lately, and I'm looking for the correct way to change my repositories to async versions. They now look more or less as follows:

```
public class MyRepo
{
  private DbContext _context;

  public MyRepo()
  {
    _context = new DbContext();
  }

  public int DoSomeStuff(int id)
  {
    var item = _context.MyModels.Where(x => x.Id == id).SingleOrDefault();    
    item.MyProperty = "abcd";
    return _context.SaveChanges();   
  } 
}
```

Example of calling this repository:

```
var myRepo = new MyRepo();
myRepo.DoSomeStuff(1);
myRepo.DoSomeStuff(2);
```

Can I just change the `DoSomeStuff` function to:

```
public async Task<int> DoSomeStuffAsync(int id)
{
  var item = await _context.MyModels.Where(x => x.Id == id).SingleOrDefaultAsync();    
  item.MyProperty = "abcd";
  return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();   
}
```

or is this the wrong way of handling the `DbContext` instance, and should it be:

```
public async Task<int> DoSomeStuffAsync(int id)
{
  using(var db = new DbContext())
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: `new DbContext()` [Why are you allocating new objects like a peasant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)?

Comment: This is just an example, I did not take DI into account yet since that will probably my next question about async repositories :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it either way, depending on the semantics you want. If you're using a shared `DbContext`, you just have to document that so your callers will only call one asynchronous method at a time.

Comment: Other asynchronous methods are the one thing you *can* call at the same time, depending on the database type and connection string. It's synchronous methods, both ones that access the database and especially the `Dispose()` method, that are never safe to call at the same time as an asynchronous method.

Comment: @hvd: Entity Framework 6 only allows a single operation per `DbContext` at a time. So `await Task.WhenAll(repo.DoSomeStuff1Async(), repo.DoSomeStuff2Async())` would fail.

Comment: Oh wow, you're right, that does indeed fail now. I'm pretty sure it used to be that `Task.WhenAll(db.Xs.ToListAsync(), db.Xs.ToListAsync())` would be unstable (multiple asynchronous calls creating entities), but `Task.WhenAll(db.Xs.Select(x => x.Id).ToListAsync(), db.Xs.Select(x => x.Id).ToListAsync())` would be fine as long as the underlying connection supported concurrent queries. The second part of my comment stands though: synchronous methods are not a good idea to call either.

Comment: So creating a `DbContext` inside each repository function allows me to do a `Task.WhenAll()` on those functions? And how do you document the `DbContext` so it's used for one method at a time?

Comment: @Marthijn: Yes. And, use whatever documentation standards your company has, e.g., xml comments.

Comment: Ah, you mean that kind of documentation. I was thinking about some great new features I never heard from :)